# How can i use java libraries in a jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to import and use regular java libraries in a jenkins pipeline Shared Library? I want to import the AWS SDK for java and using it directly in the pipeline code. Do I have to add it to the src dir of my Shared Library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Groovy Grapes](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html):

```
@Grab('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.205')
import ...
```

Comment: Is that available in a jenkinsfile? its a DSL

Comment: @red888 https://stackoverflow.com/q/42248116/6309 seems to say yes, but https://stackoverflow.com/q/46137474/6309 seems to say no. For a concrete pipeline example using Grab: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44704844/6309

Comment: According to the docs, it should be: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-third-party-libraries

Comment: This works but it seems I can't import inside a closure in groovy, not sure how to write a groovy script that imports and uses a java library and then use its methods in a jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 3):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41707846/6309), check the output of `println System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs")`

Then try and put our jar in that folder (as seen [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26651048/6309)).

This is at best a workaround though, and the "[Extending with Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#extending-with-shared-libraries)" only mentions classpath as part of an official shared library directory structure:

> The `src` directory should look like standard Java source directory structure. This directory is added to the classpath when executing Pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Example for importing a library:

```
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
pipeline{
    
}
```